# Codesandbox Invalid Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, codesandbox

I have a problem on codesandbox, that is not reproducable in normal setup.

The error is: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component." - invariant 321

1. I only use function components
2. There actually was a problem in a dependency (DraftJS)
3. Downgraded react and react-dom to 16.12 - where the error was not existing
4. Removed the DraftJS dependency mounting at all (removed the schema `widget: 'Text'`)
5. Removed some other call - to setState, not a hook - inside a setTimeout
6. Checked the `package-lock.json`, `react` and `react-dom` are the same version

The error still exists in the sandbox, when installing offline no error comes up at all.

Error was primary triggered from [src/Schema/DemoEditor.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lalande-w8cvz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FSchema%2FDemoEditor.js&theme=dark)

- changed sandbox (no DraftJS mounting, no setTimeout): https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lalande-w8cvz
- org. sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/ui-schema/demo-cra
- github project: https://github.com/ui-schema/demo-cra

Comment: The error in your question is not the error thats presented in the codesandbox

Comment: your problem is your useState, calling functions inside your set state methods, and then additionally 'watching' the functions in the array of usestate, rather than the state values

Comment: when u fix the useEffect problem, the real error is: `given store must be a valid EditorStore in SchemaEditorProvider` so theres something wrong with that as well

Comment: Actually it seems that there is some issues with codesandbox example. I've tested it locally and on [repl](https://repl.it/@elbakerino/ui-schema-cra) and it works.

Comment: @GBWDev calling functions within setState is what i do everywhere, why adding another unneeded variable beforehand? "watching" is needed, without those functions in dependencies, it is really error-prone (also my strict eslint rules would throw that normally, `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`).

"given store errror": because you didn't set the values in the state - like it was set in useEffect :)

Comment: @awran5 thanks, and i really don't know how to fix that, the original codesandbox is autogenerated from the github repository, repl and local works without any errors/warnings at all